# Kotlin projection redundancy

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

While reading about Kotlin generics type variance and projection I came up with completely unfamiliar concept to me. Can someone explain please what is the idea that the author wants to explain? Please this quote from *Kotlin in Action, MEAP*:

> There is no sense to get an `out` projection of a type parameter that already has `out` variance, such as `List<out T>`. That would mean the same as `List<T>`, because `List` is declared as `class List<out T>`. The Kotlin compiler will warn that such a projection is redundant.

There are two concrete questions here:

1. Why you ever need to add out projection on already out projected type List?
2. Even if you do so, how you get the same List?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As quoted, it would be “redundant”, thus you’d never want to do that. It simply does not add any benefit. The whole quote is related to **use-site variance**, i.e. variance *specified by the client* (corresponds to wildcards in Java). The class `List<out T>` already has a **declaration-site variance** modifier `out`, which makes the use-site application of `out` redundant.

Here's an example of **redundant client-site variance**:

```
fun <T> useList(list: List<out T>) {
    println("first element: ${list[0]}")
}
```

I applied the `out` modifier to a function parameter of type `List<T>`, this is an example of use-site variance. It is redundant which the compiler notices: `"Projection is redundant"`. It does not make it worse nor any better.

On the other hand, if you're using a **type that is not projected on declaration-site** already, it does make sense. For example, the `Array` class is not restricted in its variance: `public class Array<T>`.

Rewriting the former example to use `Array`, it suddenly makes sense to add an `out` modifier, since the parameter is only used as a producer of `T`, i.e. not in `in` position.

Example of meaningful client-site variance:

```
fun <T> useArray(arr: Array<out T>) {
    println("first element: ${arr[0]}")
}
```

#### Rule of Thumb

As a rule of thumb, corresponding to Java‘s **[PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2723538/8073652)** (Producer `extends`, Consumer `super`), you can memorize **POCI** for Kotlin (Producer `out`, Consumer `in`).

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Why you ever need to add out projection on already out projected type List?

You don't, but it may happen by accident, such as through refactoring or in a deep call chain where you lose sight of the generic parameters being passed around.

> 2. Even if you do so, how you get the same List?

In an analogy, you might consider the projection as an idempotent transform: `out out T` is the same as just `out T`.