# Kotlin Generics Error in Java

Tags: java, android, generics, kotlin, kotlin-generics

Given the following three kotlin classes:

```
abstract class UseCase<T> {
    fun execute(action: Action<T>) {
    }
}

class ConcreteUseCase : UseCase<List<String>>()

class Action<T>
```

I am unable to compile following lines in java code:

```
ConcreteUseCase s = new ConcreteUseCase();
s.execute(new Action<List<String>>());//<<<<<<< compilation error
```

[image]

Error says:

> SomeClass<java.util.List<? extends Type>> in Class cannot be applied to SomeClass<java.util.List<Type>>

I am still new to kotlin and this might be something very small but I can't seem to figure it out. I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your `ConcreteUseCase` as following:

```
class ConcreteUseCase : UseCase<List<@JvmSuppressWildcards String>>()
```

For more information visit this [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#variant-generics)

Answer (score 4):

To simply fix the Java code without touching Kotlin:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConcreteUseCase s = new ConcreteUseCase();
    Action<List<? extends String>> listAction = new Action<>();
    s.execute(listAction);
}
```

Otherwise: The [`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html) in Kotlin is declared as `interface List<out E>`, i.e. only a producer of `E`and thus your method’s parameter type `List<? extends T>` has wildcards in Java (Producer `extends`, Consumer `super`). You can use `MutableList` on Kotlin side:

```
class ConcreteUseCase : 
    UseCase<MutableList<String>>
```

This one does not use [declaration-site variance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170317/8073652) modifiers (`in`/`out`) and you’ll be able to call the method as expected.

It’s also possible to use `@JvmSuppressWildcards` as explained [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#variant-generics).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Loved your answer. I am going to use `@JvmSuppressWildcards` for now.

Comment: Nice alternative. Problem is, seems as if your fix forces the user to specify a *mutable* list, which may be undesired.

Comment: Not at all. Just used it to make clear what is going on. You can leave List as is, I added an example